# What does the ramo mean by רוֹעֶה זוֹנוֹת (shepherding harlets)

Tags: halacha, words

I am having an argument with @user6591 [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71356/5120) in the comments how to correctly understand it

The [ramo](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.154.1)

> מִי שֶׁהוּא רוֹעֶה זוֹנוֹת וְאִשְׁתּוֹ קוֹבֶלֶת עָלָיו, אִם יֵשׁ עֵדוּת בַּדָּבָר, שֶׁרָאוּ אוֹתוֹ עִם **מְנָאֲפִים** אוֹ שֶׁהוֹדָה, יֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁכּוֹפִין אוֹתוֹ לְהוֹצִיא, אֲבָל מִשּׁוּם שֶׁמְבִיאִין לוֹ יְלָדִים כּוּתִים אֵין לָחוּשׁ, דִּלְמָא מְשַׁקְרִים עָלָיו (חִדּוּשֵׁי אֲגֻדָּה דִּיבָמוֹת):

Ber haitiv there

> זונות. ראובן שבא על א''א וחוזר בתשובה ואשתו תובעת ממנו גט וליתן לה כתובה. פסק חכם צבי בתשובתו סימן קל''ג דאין כופין אותו להוציא. דל''ד לרועה זונות דמוחזק לכך ועומד במרדו ורועה זונות יאבד הון וסופו לא יהיה בידו לפרנסה משא''כ כאן דשב בתשובה ע''ש:

[Aruch hashulchan 154.16](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14243&pgnum=637)

See [mishlai 29.3](http://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.29.3?with=all)

**Is it to use the harlets or to provide (pimp) them?**

If it is to use them how to understand מְנָאֲפִים (above), (is it not in the male form?)?

Comment: Since the reason given is he will lose his fortune, it can hardly apply to "pimp" them!

Comment: @newcomer how do you understand מְנָאֲפִים, (is it not in the male form?)?

Comment: @newcomer the aruch hashulchan does not bring the money reason

Comment: It simply means with other people like him @hazoriz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rama is making a literary reference, to [Mishlei 29:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2829.htm):

אִישׁ-אֹהֵב חָכְמָה, יְשַׂמַּח אָבִיו;    וְרֹעֶה זוֹנוֹת, יְאַבֶּד-הוֹן
"Whoso loveth wisdom rejoiceth his father; but he that keepeth company with harlots wasteth his substance."

[Rashi](http://daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=31&perek=29&mefaresh=rashi) writes there:
ורועה. מחבר לו זונות כמשמעו. ורבותינו אמרו האומר שמועה זו נאה אשננה וזו אינה נאה לא אשננה, וסיוע במקרא שאין זונות במקרא מלא אלא זה בלבד.

And Ibn Ezra [writes](http://daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=31&perek=29&mefaresh=ezra):
ורועה -
מן רעך, או מענין: כמרעיתם וישבעו, כלומר מפרנס הזונות והעד: יאבד הון.

meaning that he either makes "friends" with or else pays harlots. And the proof is that he is losing his wealth.

If that is the meaning of the pasuk, then this may well also be the meaning of the Rama.

Comment: +1 It may, but how do you understand מְנָאֲפִים, (is it not in the male form?)?

Comment: Can he not give them parnasa by pimping them?

Comment: then the proof for the Ibn Ezra wouldn't be the end of the pasuk, that he loses wealth. the pasuk is someone who gives away all his money by indulging in prostitutes.

Comment: OK, how about "מנאפים" ?

Comment: It is the gender neutral plural.  If there are either witnesses to then engaging in intercourse (menaafim) or he admits it...

Comment: so please put in your answer that מנאפים is the husband and the prostitute

Comment: I just realized that they saw him **with** the מנאפים so it can not include him, and it can not be (him) engaging in intercourse 

Comment: You are right that it is a noun. Still means either intercourse or else keeping the harlots company. The problem is that once again rama is being poetic, and that obscures his meaning. Im menaafim is a literary reference to tehillim 50.

Comment: wow!!! Nice tehilim 

Comment: see links in my answer http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71524/5120 were they understand the even ezer also my way

Comment: But it seems that you are right

Answer (score 1):

http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/psk/psk.asp?id=710
there is a psak din of a bais din in israel with a pilpul of different ways of understanding it one of them being also to pimp them

> או כל סרסור לזונות

but it seems that there final decision is that it means married woman more then once

here they bring the whole haguda (the ramo's source)
http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/psk/psk.asp?id=1395

> ‏"פעם אחת בא מעשה לידי, לאה טוענת על ראובן שהיה רועה זונות והוא כופר, ופסקתי שאם תביא עדים שהוא כן, יוציא ויתן כתובה, איבעית אימא קרא ואיבעית אימא גמרא ואיבעית אימא סברא. קרא דכתיב אם תקח נשים על בנותי, ואיבעית אימא גמרא דאמרינן הכא והוא דאפשר בסיפוקייהו ובנדון זה כתיב ורועה זונות יאבד הון, ואיבעית אימא סברא דגרע מכל הני דפרק המדיר.‏
>
> ודוקא שיש עדים וכו', גם אמרתי שיעידו העדים זה שלא בפני זה ויחקרו אותם בדרישה וחקירה כמו על דיני נפשות. ואחרי שפסקתי בכתב שלחו קרובי האשה תשובה הר"מ ז"ל, הועתק מכתיבת ידו והאריך בו מאד וכתב כל הני טעמי שכתבתי, וסוף דבריו היכא דאיכא סהדי או כשהודה מעצמו כייפינן ליה להוציא."‏

see
http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/psk/psk.asp?id=576